# computer graphics Cpp program

Tags: c++, bgi

```
#include<graphics.h>
int main()
{
    int gd=DETECT;
    int gm;
    initgraph(&gm,&gd,"C:\\TC\\BGI");
    arc(200,200,0,130,50);
    closegraph();
    getch();

}
```

giving the error
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

and main.exe has stopped working

Comment: Voting close as off-topic (Why this code is not working) for now. Anyway  what OS ... BGI is for MS-DOS if you are not in MS-DOS nor emulated like DOSBOX then do not be surprised. For windows apps use WinBGI or even better no BGI at all. btw why `closegraph()` before the `getch`?

Comment: OS is Ms-DOS. and closegraph() is just because, might code will run. I know that doesn't need here but to run this simple code use that also. Last time same code same compiler,  program runs easily what happen this time doesn't find till now..

Comment: if I remember correctly `closegraph()` deactivates graphic mode so if returned to text mode your gfx is clear out. As your `getch()` is called after rendering my bet is you render stuff clear it out and wait for keypress ... seeing nothing as you clear it out immediately swap the last two lines. BTW  What does it mean: `main.exe has stopped working`? hang up  ? crash ? exit ?  There are no other options for non TSR EXE in MS-DOS. If you got error message like that then you are not in MS-DOS at all

Comment: Sir, I'm MS-DOS user... and last time when use exactly same code(i think) that runs easily. But this time what happen didn't run. That's why I post a simple question on StackOverflow. Because at first it looks easy but what's the error not known till now. Swap two line is done.. use some other function is also done... compiler uninstall..install done but still same problem... And yes, it's MS-DOS sir :)